# mui autocomplete with react-hook-form: defaultValue in formData

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm setting the defaultValue of the Autocopmlete component as below:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo={freeSolo}
      options={options}
      renderInput={params => {
        return <TextField {...params} label={label} margin="normal" variant="outlined" onChange={onChange} />
      }}
      onChange={(event, values, reason) => onChange(values)}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
    />
  )}
/>
```

the value is well displayed based on the defaultValue.
However when I click on the submit button, the value of the Autocomplete field is always undefined if I don't use the autocomplete component.
Here are how I register the hook and component (simplified code)

```
const customerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  route: yup.string().nullable()
})
  
const {control, handleSubmit} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(customerSchema)
  })

  const onSubmit = formData => {
    console.log(formData) // autocomplete is undefined if no action on the autocomplete 
  }

<form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
 <AutoCompleteInput
        control={control}
        name="route"
        label="route"
        options={customers_routes.map(option => option.route_name)}
        defaultValue={customer.route}
        freeSolo={false}
      />
  <Button type="submit">
        Update
      </Button>
  </form>
```

What should I do to have the route field always available in the form data when I click on submit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use `defaultValues` option with `useForm`:

```
const {control, handleSubmit} = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(customerSchema),
  defaultValues: { route: customer.route },
});
```

and instead of sending `defaultValue` prop to `AutoComplete` you can use `value` prop, like this:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo={freeSolo}
        options={options}
        renderInput={(params) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          );
        }}
        onChange={(event, values, reason) => onChange(values)}
        value={value}
      />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: this is working great! Thanks.
however I have some issue with TypeScript that I am not sure how to fix:   
    TS2322: Type 'Control<{ route: any; }, object>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues, object>'.   The types of '_options.resolver' are incompatible between these types.     Type 'Resolver<{ route: any; }, object>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<FieldValues, object>'.

Comment: You're welcome, maybe https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-ui-library-ts-forked-qjgkx could help to solve TypeScript issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplest way to use an Autocomplete with react hook from , render your `Autocomplete` component inside Controller from react hook from, use `onChange` and `value` from the `render` function  to control the value

```js
<Controller
control={control}
name="type"
rules={{
  required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
}}
render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    options={['field', 'select', 'multiple', 'date']}
    onChange={(event, values) => onChange(values)}
    value={value}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="type"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    )}
  />
)}
```